# Storing data in map from a map while reading from CSV

Tags: java, hashmap, aspose

I m working on a project where i need to read data from csv and store it in map. I m using aspose to read csv, can you please help me guide me how can i read store data in Map?

I have tried storing data in map then storing it again in map to get values using column and row.

Link to the csv file is shown below..
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0By64gw5ORtRjWXJ6SzZfMXd0SE0/view?usp=sharing

---

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> hmap=new HashMap<Integer,Map<String,String>>();
            int startRow = 2;
            int startcol = 0;
            Integer count = 0;
            for (int i = startRow; i < trows; i++) {
                for (int j = startcol; j <= tcols-1; j++) {
                    System.out.print("----:"+ i + "    "+j);
                    map.put((String)cells.get(2, j).getValue(), (String)cells.get(i, j).getValue());
                }
                hmap.put(count, map);
                count++;
            }  

                System.out.println("map size: " + hmap.size());
```

Output is :-

```
 -----------------START------------------
    --------------------------- com.aspose.cells.Cells@5f341870
    range values in aspose: Aspose.Cells.Range [ Sheet1!A1:L14 ]
    Total Rows:14
    Total Cols:12
    map size: 12
    0 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    1 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    2 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    3 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    4 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    5 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    6 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    7 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    8 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    9 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    10 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}
    11 - {template=yes, DML=yes, prod=yes, dev=yes, stage=yes, test=yes, Dump=yes, uat=yes, Project_Name=data-portfolio-ii, Code=Yes (inside trunk), DDL=yes, local=yes}

    -----------------END------------------
```

---

Thank you for helping in advance.....

Comment: What is not working ? Could you limit the code to that ? Using methods (getHeader, getColumn, get###) would be more readable instead of that huge method. Of course, a [mcve] is needed to get help on that.

Comment: offtopic: in java you can replace the backslashes in your paths with regular ones like any civilised OS uses them ;)

Comment: not OT: would you mind posting a code example which is not polluted with console-debugging and empty loops? make an effort to help people help you

Comment: Here: `hmap.put(count, map);`you put the same `map`object for evey line. You need to instanciate a new map in each loop.

Comment: can you please tell me how should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a map for each row so that you do not put the same object for each row in your final map:

```
Map<Integer,Map<String,String>> hmap=new HashMap<Integer,Map<String,String>>();
            int startRow = 2;
            int startcol = 0;
            Integer count = 0;
            for (int i = startRow; i < trows; i++) {
                Map<String,String> rowMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
                for (int j = startcol; j <= tcols-1; j++) {
                    System.out.print("----:"+ i + "    "+j);
                    rowMap .put((String)cells.get(2, j).getValue(), (String)cells.get(i, j).getValue());
                }
                hmap.put(count, rowMap );
                count++;
            }  

            System.out.println("map size: " + hmap.size());
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, you need to check it as the correct answer.

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. See help there: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers